# Color Command Does Not Execute In Batch File

Tags: batch-file, variables, colors

I recently started making a new project. I would like to change the color by typing the color codes for BG and Text with `set /p`, but when I join the BG color variable and the text color variable, the cmd window closes.

Here's the code

```bat
:ColorText
CLS

SET /P "Input.User.SysConfigTextColor=Please enter the text Color:"

IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%" == "A" GOTO :ColorBG
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%" == "B" GOTO :ColorBG
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%" == "C" GOTO :ColorBG
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%" == "D" GOTO :ColorBG
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%" == "E" GOTO :ColorBG
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%" == "F" GOTO :ColorBG
SET /A "Input.User.SysConfigTextColora=%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%"
IF %Input.User.SysConfigTextColora% GTR -1 IF %Input.User.SysConfigTextColora% LSS 10 GOTO :ColorBG
GOTO :ColorText

:ColorBG
CLS
SET /P "Input.User.SysConfigBGColor=Please enter the background Color:"

IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%" == "A" GOTO :ColorD
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%" == "B" GOTO :ColorD
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%" == "C" GOTO :ColorD
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%" == "D" GOTO :ColorD
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%" == "E' GOTO :ColorD
IF /I "%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%" == "F" GOTO :ColorD
SET /A "Input.User.SysConfigBGColora=%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%"
IF %Input.User.SysConfigBGColora% GTR -1 IF %Input.User.SysConfigBGColora% LSS 10 GOTO :ColorD
GOTO :ColorBG

:ColorD
CLS
SET Var.System.Color=%Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%
ECHO %Input.User.SysConfigBGColor%%Input.User.SysConfigTextColor%>"%~Dp0C\Blah\Color.dat"
```

Please help me find out the problem, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Learn to debug.  Open up a cmd prompt and execute your batch file from the cmd prompt.  You are not using @ECHO OFF, so you should see the error plain as day.

Comment: @Squashman thanks for your advice, will try that

Comment: Should also mention to remove the clear screen commands as well.

Comment: @Squashman trying that too!

Comment: Your code was throwing a syntax error because of this **"E'**

Comment: @Squashman I am confused, which "**E**" Do you mean?

Comment: Like I said before if you execute your code with echo on and remove your clear screen and run the batch file from a cmd prompt you will see it error out on the line that has a **SINGLE QUOTE** and not a **DOUBLE QUOTE**.

Comment: @Squashman sorry for late reply but now I found the "E" that throw syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about we simplify your logic a bit.  Just so you know, making large variable names increases your environment size and slows down your batch file.  Here is a better way to validate the user input.

```
 @echo off
 :ColorText
 CLS

 SET /P "TextColor=Please enter the text Color:"

 FOR %%G IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F) DO IF /I "%TextColor%"=="%%G" GOTO ColorBG
 GOTO ColorText

 :ColorBG
 cls
 SET /P "BGColor=Please enter the background Color:"

 FOR %%G IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F) DO IF /I "%BGColor%"=="%%G" GOTO ColorD
 GOTO ColorBG

 :ColorD

 SET Var.System.Color=%BGColor%%TextColor%
 ECHO %BGColor%%TextColor%
 pause
```

Comment: I knew my var. name is way too long but that fits in my var. naming method. Anway I'll try your method

Comment: Just checked your answer. It worked like a charm! Thanks for all your help!